# Adding the results of pyspark kmeans algorithm to dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, k-means

I have a spark dataframe containing geo-information.

```
my_df.show(2)

## +----+----+-----------+----------+
## | x0 | x1 | longitude | latitude |
## +----+----+-----------+----------+
## | ...| ...| 51.043    | 13.6847  | 
## | ...| ...| 42.6753   | 23.3218  |
```

I took the longitude and the latitude out of my dataframe and caluculated some centerpoints with the kmeans library from pyspark.

```
#Trains a k-means model
k = 120
model = KMeans.train(dataset, k)
print ("Final centers: " + str(model.clusterCenters))
```

the output

```
Final centers: [array([ 51.04307692,  13.68474126]), array([-33.434     , -70.58366667]), array([ 42.67533333,  23.32185981]), array([ 45.876, -61.492]), array([ 53.07465714,   8.4655    ]), array([   4.594,  114.262]), array([ 48.15665306,  11.54269728]), array([ 51.51729851,   7.49838806]), array([ 48.76316125,   9.15357859]), ....
```

Anyone an idea how to add the matching centers to my dataframe?

```
## +----+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
## | x0 | x1 | longitude | latitude | mean_long | mean_lat |
## +----+----+-----------+----------+-----------+----------+
## | ...| ...| 51.043    | 13.6847  | 50.000    | 15.000   |
## | ...| ...| 42.6753   | 23.3218  | 50.000    | 15.000   |
```

Answer (score 0):

If you decided to use `DataFrames` you should use new `pyspark.ml` API, not the legacy `pyspark.mllib`. It provides a number of clustering methods, including K-Means, and its predict method will attach prediction column to the `DataFrame`.

Please check ML documentation for details (API and required input types):

- https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-clustering.html#k-means

Comment: Good suggest, but I'm currently working on a cluster with Spark 1.6.3 which doesn't have a python implementation for k-means in psyspark.ml

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps!
(**note** - I have taken sample data from Spark documentation page)

```
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.clustering import KMeans
import pandas as pd

#generate data
data = [(Vectors.dense([0.0, 0.0]),), (Vectors.dense([1.0, 1.0]),),
        (Vectors.dense([9.0, 8.0]),), (Vectors.dense([8.0, 9.0]),)]
df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(data, ["features"])
df.show()

#run kmeans clustering model
kmeans = KMeans(k=2, seed=1)
model = kmeans.fit(df)
predictions=model.transform(df).withColumnRenamed("prediction","cluster_id")

centers = model.clusterCenters()
#preprocessing centers so that it can be joined with predictions dataframe
centers_p_df = pd.DataFrame(centers)
centers_p_df.insert(0, 'new_col', range(0, len(centers_p_df)))
centers_df = sqlContext.createDataFrame(centers_p_df, schema=['cluster_id','centers_col1','centers_col2'])

final_df = predictions.join(centers_df, on="cluster_id").drop("cluster_id")
final_df.show()
```